# Change a value in column of a CSV file

Tags: powershell, csv

I'm trying to find a way to change the value of all the entries in the 'Available Person' column in my csv file using PowerShell.

If the value is 'Y' it should be changed to '1' and if the value is 'N' it should be changed to ')':

```
Branch Number,      CoreID,     Available Person,      Workstation
8002,           FMD354800200,   Y,
8002,           FMD354800201,   Y,
8002,           FMD354800202,   N,
8002,           FMD354800203,   N,
8002,           FMD354800204,   Y,
```

Here's what I've tried:

```
$csv=Import-Csv user.csv' | $csv | %{ if($_.'Available Person' -eq "Y") {$_.'Available Person'="1"} } $csv|export-csv user1.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Can you show the code of what you have tried and where you are running into issues?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is some example code for how you might solve this with a `Switch` statement

```
$ImportedCSV = Import-CSV C:\user.csv
$NewCSV = Foreach ($Entry in $ImportedCsv) {
    Switch ($Entry."Available Person") {
        Y {$Entry."Available Person" = "1"}
        N {$Entry."Available Person" = ")"}
        default {Write-Error "$($Entry."Branch Number") has unexpected value for Available Person"}
    }
    $Entry
}
$NewCSV | Export-CSV C:\user1.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Answer (score 3):

try this

```
(Import-Csv C:\temp\LastAnalyse.csv | 
    %{$_.'Available Person'=if ($_.Path -eq 'Y') {'1'} elseif ($_.Path -eq 'N') {')'} else {$_.'Available Person'}; $_}) | 
        Export-Csv  C:\temp\LastAnalyse.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$csv = Import-Csv -Path 'C:\TEMP\41768152.csv'

$csv | ogv

foreach ($row in $csv)
{
    $row.'Available Person' = $row.'Available Person' -ireplace 'Y','1' -ireplace 'N',')'
}

$csv | ogv
```

Comment: doesnt work, if 'Available Person' = 'PAPY IS A NOOBY' your solution replace by  'PAP1 IS A (OOB1'   :)